# linking two routers with cat5 cable

Tags: home-networking

I need to link two routers with cat5 cable to share one satellite broadband connection. The reason is the wireless computers in another house can not see the wireless router where the dish is located. I want to feed the broadband from the dish to both routers. I want to split the lan output of the modem with a network switch. Will that work? Also, both routers need only to provide internet to wireless laptops in their range, not communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's even easier than that... Just plug the input (WAN) port on the remote router into an output (LAN) port of the router closest to the dish.  Then configure the remote router to be in "bridged" mode.

Comment: I can't find a setting for bridged mode. Is that the same as setting it as an access point?

Comment: you can alternately turn off DHCP on the remote router